# Trouble with R function

Tags: r, function

I try to create a function. But when I change the sequence of it then it create NA values out. Any particular reason to it? Thanks

```
new<-function(x){
    min2<-NULL
    min1<-NULL
    len<-length(unique(x))
for (i in 1:(len-1)) 
    min2[i]<-sort(x,partial=(len-i+1))[(len-i+1)]
    min1[i]<-sort(x,partial=(len-i))  [(len-i)]
    return((min1))  
}


x<-c(1,11,40,120)

new(x)

[1] 120  40  11




new<-function(x){
    min2<-NULL
    min1<-NULL
    len<-length(unique(x))
for (i in 1:(len-1)) 
    min1[i]<-sort(x,partial=(len-i))  [(len-i)]
    min2[i]<-sort(x,partial=(len-i+1))[(len-i+1)]
    return((min1))  
}


x<-c(1,11,40,120)

new(x)

[1] NA  NA  11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot curly parentheses around the expression you want to repeat in you `for` loop:

```
new<-function(x){
    min2<-NULL
    min1<-NULL
    len<-length(unique(x))
    for (i in 1:(len-1)) {
      min2[i]<-sort(x,partial=(len-i+1))[(len-i+1)]
      min1[i]<-sort(x,partial=(len-i))  [(len-i)] 
    }
    return(min1)  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats very silly of me to forget about the parentheses.